# Progress visibility not working in list view footer

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I am using pagination in my list view and i am displaying a progress bar(small) in list view footer when user scroll down to end of the list view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);    
myListView.addFooter(view).
```

Then i am setting my adapter as follows

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getFooterView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(BaseActivity.getActivity(), 0, progressBar, myArrayList);
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In my adapter class i am settings progress bar visibility in getView() method as follows.

```
 if(position == MAX_RECORDS)
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Some code goes here.
    } else
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But ProgressBar not disappears when list has no data to fetch. Please help me.

Comment: I think best solution for you to use this method. `mListView.removeFooterView(v)`. And remove footer view.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but this is not working either.

Comment: try to set interface call in activity from adapter class and then set visibility to visible...

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
if(position == MAX_RECORDS-1)
```

position starts with 0

**UPDATE**

Just trying to understand your code here:

```
if(position == MAX_RECORDS-1) 
    { 
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Some code goes here. 
    }
```

above block will get executed when the last row is displayed. since getview is called for all rows before, and hopefully you are using convertview, the else block will not be executed again.

Net result is : dialog will be visible indefinitely.

If I am right you want to show the dialog when loading data and hide it when load completes. There are two scenarios:

- you fetch data in one go
- you fetch data when last row is displayed.

Can you shed some light which one of above is true?

Comment: Hey @Kay thanks, i am using MAX_RECORDS-1 already just forgot to post, do you have any other idea about this problem.

Comment: Last one is true in my case i fetch data when last row is displayed

Comment: so if you are fetching 20 records per call then max_record should be 20, then 40 then 60 and so on

Comment: if max_record is updating, then it means when there is no data to fetch the progress will not be made gone. Example : if you pull 80-100 records and thats the last of it then on (position == 99) progressdialog will be visible and there will be no further getview calls so will never be invisible.

Comment: to overcome the same, you need to have the Actual Max count of the data on server i.e. 100 in my above example. OR when server returns no more data to fetch, hide the progress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84676/discussion-between-user3804327-and-kay).

Answer (score 0):

Set progressBar to visible state initially and use the same code itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.Changes in this line will help you

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

instead of

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getFooterView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```